# Language parameter for google maps link

Tags: google-maps

It's not for API.
It just link, for example I want to give some link:

http://maps.google.com/maps?&z=16&q=59.4195272,24.803938000000016

And forward user by this link for his language [en,et,ru ..] map version to http://maps.google.com/

Is it possible put in url-link to http://maps.google.com/  some parameter which will define language version  for google map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

edit:

```
?hl=<language> or &hl=<language>
```

Pick the language code from the same wikipedia article below.

Do you know the language preference of the person you are sending the link to?

If so you can send a different tld to get it in the language default for that location

i.e.

```
http://maps.google.fr <- French
http://maps.google.de <- German
```

Check out [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google_domains) for the full list.

If this is not what you are asking for, please re-word or add information to your question by editing the original.

Comment: I know about tld, but if I will write mistake I got error, instead of parameter, if google accept some langugage parameter for http://maps.google.com like for API, it will solve my task. For example http://maps.google.com/maps?&z=16&q=59.4195272,24.803938000000016&language=fr